# return correct format for mysql DateTime field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a DateTime field in a mysql table with a value coming from a js script.

So far I have:

```
let expiredAt = new Date();
expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt + process.env.JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION);
```

but it returns

> 'Thu Mar 28 2024 04:31:40 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)

that is throwing error in mysql since it is not the correct format. I should be inserting:

> 2024-03-28 04:31:40

How can I return it? I know there are several similar questions that are focusing on formatting the date on a specific locale. What I want is to convert it to something that is not a locale

Comment: function setSeconds will return a timestamp and not the format give in sample 

how do you get the `'Thu Mar 28 2024 04:31:40 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)` ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis you are right, that was a typo

Comment: Assuming you want to get a date that is X seconds from now, consider using `new Date(new Date().getTime() + X * 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fromat the date to return the right format you want, here is an helper function that can do it

```
function formatDate(dateString) {
    // Parse the input date string
    var date = new Date(dateString);

    // Extract date components
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // Months are zero-based
    var day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var seconds = date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

    // Construct the formatted date string
    var formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    return formattedDate;
}
```

here is how to use it:

```
let expiredAt = new Date();
expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt + process.env.JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION);
const formatedDate = formatDate(expiredAt)
```

now you can store the `formatedDate` to the sql db.

---

EDIT:

in order to avoid different locale , and "escape" the locale. you can set the date to be always utc. and use setUTC methods to format the date in a way that it will be always utc. this way you will "avoid" locale, by insuring you always store utc format.

For example you can generate the date with `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` and/or setSeconds with `setUTCSeconds`.

also i see you are using it to set seconds to add the expire seconds to the date, im not sure what is the exact use case, but you can think about manipulating the date on the backend, so you will use your server  locale, therefore, all the dates will use the same base date, even if converting to utc (or not) . you can check the expire on the backend and be sure its always the same locale..

But basicaly to answer your question about locale, there is no way to avoid locale on js, atleast from what i know. time stamp will be always based on a locale

By the way, this is what mongoDB is doing. i know we are talking about SQL. but just as a reference, mongoDB is converting all dates to be UTC.

Comment: One thing you can do, is to set the date to be UTC always. so you will have always one locale (UTC) . then if you want to convert it to any time zone, you can always do it from UTC format.

Comment: From what i know, you can run away from locale on js. you can use formatting like my answer or toLocale like oyu wrote in your question. as i wrote on the above comment, a good way to avoid locale, is to use one locale (like utc) so all your db will have the same date format and time. in case of showing the user their time zone or to use their time zone you can simple put it back inside new Date() and it will show the user time zone. you can always pick one locale for the server and use it aswell..

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `Date` instance into a string and then format it accordingly.

One approach is to use JavaScript's built-in method `toISOString()`. In this example you also need to use `slice()` and `replace()` to remove the 'T' character from the string (T indicates where the time part of the string begins).

```
let expiredAt = new Date();

expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt + process.env.JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION);

console.log(expiredAt.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '));
```